# WordPress blog with minimal integration

Tags: php, wordpress

Forgive my ignorance - I've been looking at WordPress for only a few hours so far...

My requirement is to add a blog, and later, a twitter feed, to an existing website. I don't think I want to fully embrace WordPress just yet so am looking to add a new page to my existing website, say `blog.php` and for its content to look something like this:

```
<html>
   ...   
   <!-- My existing HTML -->
   ...
   <?php
      wp_render_posts(10); // TODO - How? Render last 10 blog posts
   ?>
   ...   
   <!-- My existing HTML -->
   ...
</html>
```

**Question:** Is there a method like `wp_render_posts` that I can use without the rest that WordPress brings?

I accept I will still want to deploy the rest for the admin side if nothing else (and obviously the database).

*Note: I would rather avoid iFrames.*

Comment: You can use `require_once( "/path/to/wp-load.php" );` and then just use the regular WordPress functions [described in the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop), but IMO this is more trouble and work than just placing WordPress in the /blog/ subdir.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Responding to my own question after further investigation...

Firstly as Horaland suggests - installing WordPress in a subdirectory is a good approach. That, coupled with use of a custom [theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) allows complete control over what features of WordPress you use.

### Creating a Theme

Themes are simple to create - for full information check out something like [How to create a WordPress theme](https://www.siteground.co.uk/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress_create_theme.htm) and some of the simpler themes, like [WordPress 2015](https://wordpress.org/themes/twentyfifteen/).

All of your theme files will need to be placed in a directory *my-simple-theme* under the *themes* directory of the WordPress installation. The theme will require activation from the admin console.

#### Example

You may wish to create the following files;

**index.php**

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section class="my-posts-wrapper-class">

    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <h4>Posted on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?></h4>
        <div class="my-post-class">
            <?php the_content(__('(more...)')); ?>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>

</section>

<!-- Optional -->
<section>
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>>
```

**sidebar.php**

```
<aside>
    <h2><?php _e('Categories'); ?></h2>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_list_cats('sort_column=name&optioncount=1&hierarchical=0'); ?>
    </ul>
    <h2><?php _e('Archives'); ?></h2>
    <ul>
        <?php wp_get_archives('type=monthly'); ?>
    </ul>
</aside>
```

**header.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- My site's HEAD html -->
    
    <!-- 
        If installing WordPress in a subdirectory, 
        modifiy the document's BASE to ensure CSS and JS imports
        don't need modificaiton.
    -->
    <base href="..">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- My site's NAV and more, e.g. -->
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            ...
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

**footer.php**

```
    <footer>
        <!-- My site's FOOTER html -->
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
/*
    WordPress specific styles.
    You site's core CSS could be imported in index.php.
*/
```

Comment: This still requires you to have a separate standalone installation of WordPress. Themes are an integral part of wordpress. You're basically saying my answer wasn't right but giving the same answer.

Comment: Yes, agreed. I hope it complements your answer. Apologies, I wasn't saying you're wrong, but I have gone into more detail as to how you can more simply integrate with your existing site using a drastically cut down version of WordPress using themes. As an aside, I personally don't feel that warrants a downvote.

Comment: Perhaps I felt it was obvious that it'd need to be installed in a subdirectory but accepted your answer given that that was all I had understood at the time. Now knowing that a custom theme allows complete control over what features of WordPress you use, I believe this to be the more complete answer.

Answer (score 2):

When I'm adding a WordPress blog as an extra section on an existent site I simply install it to a different directory.

So during the install it will ask you where you want it installed, choose /blog/ and WordPress will install completely seperatly to your existing site. Both the existent site and Wordpress blog exist in isolation, effectively 2 separate sites,  but you can add navigation back and forwards so to the user they are seamlessly integrated. That way you can also update WordPress easily without breaking anything.

Comment: Ok thanks - I guess I'll take a look at this. Just feel like the whole of WordPress may be overkill for me, but will see once I've got it up and running properly.

Comment: It is overkill for what you want. But so is integrating it externally. There are plenty of simple blog scripts around to use.

Comment: It's only overkill in term of features. In terms of time and maintenance doing it with an off the shelf Word Press installation will save you loads of time and effort especially if your not experienced with the WordPress API.